# Combining Regex using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I currently have 2 regular expressions to match. I need to match either of them

I am currently using this code:

```
$string = '000.400.101';

$regex1 = "^(000\.000\.|000\.100\.1|000\.[36])";
$regex2 = "^(000\.400\.0|000\.400\.100)";

$result = (preg_match('/'.$regex1.'/', $string) ||
           preg_match('/'.$regex2.'/', $string)) ? 1 : 0 ;
```

I would like to shorten this and clean it up a little. Would the below be equivalent:

```
$result = (preg_match('/'.$regex1.'|'.$regex2.'/', $string)) ? 1 : 0 ;
```

Comment: That looks right, does it not work? Do you need the regex defined separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try consolidating everything into the following single regex:

```
000\.(?:[36]|000\.|100\.1|400\.(?:0|100))
```

## Demo

```
$result = preg_match('/000\.(?:[36]|000\.|100\.1|400\.(?:0|100))/', $string) ? 1 : 0;
```

And [here is a link](http://rextester.com/JVM68624) to a demo in PHP showing that the code works.

By the way, if you have the general need to regex match IP addresses, I think this general problem should be very well covered already on Stack Overflow and within PHP, and you should search around for something which might help you.

Comment: Thanks. It isnt actually for IP addresses. It is for response codes received via an api. They represent either an accept or decline for a credit card transaction. Examples below...<br>

Accept...
000.100.111
000.100.112
000.300.000
000.300.101
000.400.000
000.400.020

Decline...
000.400.102
000.400.103
000.400.104
800.100.100
800.100.150
800.100.151

I hacve tried your consolidated regex and it seems to work, thank you